# Multi-signature Transaction in Hyper-ledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to have transaction signed by 2-3 specific persons, in Hyper-ledger Fabric. Like, if a seller is trading/selling his asset then this transaction should only be committed and transferred asset, if the buyer and the trading Authority have signed this transaction. How can I achieve this? is it have to do something with the endorsement policy?

---

Can it be done with composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it can be achieved by endorsement policy. As of Fabric 1.3. there are two ays to set up the endorsement policy. you can either

1) set up an endorsement policy for a chaincode, which means all transactions on that chaincode will abide by that policy. For your case, you set a policy that needs two signatories (i.e. two peers)

or, more granular,

2) set up an endorsement policy for each asset. That means any transaction involving that asset/key will need to be endorsed by those two signatories.

Comment: how can I setup/write those endorsement policies? any useful resource/tutorial? will it be possible in hyperledger composer?

Comment: This is a good doc https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/endorsement-policies.html not sure how to do it in composer, but I am sure it can be done

Comment: googling led me to this https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information